# Pick the first letter and put it above the content group

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list which looks kind of like this:

```
<ul class="mylist">
    <li>AAA</li>
    <li>AAA</li>
    <li>AAA</li>
    <li>BBB</li>
    <li>BBB</li>
    <li>CCC</li>
</ul>
```

I would now like to add the first letter of the content above the content group.

Here is an example of how the result would look:

```
<ul class="mylist">
    <li><strong>A</strong></li>
    <li>AAA</li>
    <li>AAA</li>
    <li>AAA</li>
    <li><strong>B</strong></li>
    <li>BBB</li>
    <li>BBB</li>
    <li><strong>C</strong></li>
    <li>CCC</li>
</ul>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: please use google "how to iterate li in ul jquery", this will get you here: https://api.jquery.com/each/  then you need to make an implementation or attempt and post it here.  This is more than doable, your question should end up being "this isn't working" or "how can i make this algorithm faster?"

Comment: You're looking for a JS/JQ wrapper there. You could do what @abc123 suggested and look online, tons of resources for this exact issue. Once you understand the concept, you could put the code away in a plugin or function and just call it on the tables you want wrapped. That being said, if you've tried a few approaches and can't crack it, we can all be of more use in diagnosing that problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fairly simple with jQuery - see the code comments for explanation.

```
// shorthand for on document load
$(function() {
    // a variable to store our current first letter
    var currentFirstLetter;

    // for every child of mylist
    $('.mylist').children().each(function() {

    // take the first character of its content
    var thisLetter = $(this)[0].innerHTML.substr(0,1).toLowerCase();

    // if its different to our current first letter then add the required element
    // and update our current first letter
    if (thisLetter !== currentFirstLetter) {
        $(this).before("<li><strong>" + thisLetter.toUpperCase() + "</strong></li>");
      currentFirstLetter = thisLetter;
    }
  });
});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bigalreturns/tv9g0nbw/)

Comment: Thank you, this is working fine but it is case insensitive. So If you would add `<li>aAA</li>`, it will add another **a**.

Comment: You can just manipulate the strings with toLowerCase and toUpperCase methods

Comment: Oh wow ... this is just perfect! Thank you very much! You saved my day! :)